# как получить url из status bar хрома через расширение javascript?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

есть ли возможность получить url в google chrome через JS(как расширения) под указателем мышки перед нажатием на url или получить url  из status bar  хрома ?

Comment: Попробуйте слушать событие `mousemove`. каждый раз когда событие будет генерироваться, оно будет получать объект `event` у которого есть поле `target`, в нем содержиться элемент находящийся под курсором. Не знаю как это делается в chrome extensions, но в js логика была бы [такая](http://jsfiddle.net/6q8g37bk/)

Comment: Спасибо за ответ , но не совсем подходит этот метод  не все url  может показать   ,  может есть способ получить данные  из status bar  хрома  или chrome api ?